# How to send a portion of an output to a file?

Tags: powershell

I'm trying to write a portion of a PS output to a file. Currently I have it configured to use the out-file command, but that writes the entire output. Is there a way to specify what columns to write to the file?

Comment: Please keep in mind that we cannot see your screen and we cannot read your mind. You will have to explain what output from what command you want to export. Please show the code you used so far and maybe an example of the expected output

Comment: PS C:\WINDOWS\system32> get-localgroupmember -name "administrators"

ObjectClass Name                          PrincipalSource
----------- ----                          ---------------
User        DESKTOP-N35KFA9\17175         MicrosoftAccount
User        DESKTOP-N35KFA9\Administrator Local

Comment: I am just trying to write the Name column, not the ObjectClass or PrincipalSource column

Comment: Please ... in the future ... add additional information to your question - not as comments. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2):

PowerShell's great evolutionary leap was to send *objects* through the pipeline, not just *text* or *raw bytes*.

Therefore, you can access the *properties* of objects output by PowerShell cmdlets such as [`Get-LocalGroupMember`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.localaccounts/get-localgroupmember) via cmdlets such as [`Select-Object`](https://learn.microsoft.com/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.utility/select-object) or, in this case, since you only want the *value* of *one* of the input objects' properties, [`ForEach-Object`](https://learn.microsoft.com/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/foreach-object):

```bash
Get-LocalGroupMember -Name Administrators | # get all users in the group
  ForEach-Object Name | # extract their name
  Out-File NamesOfUsersInTheAdministratorsGroup.txt
```

Use [`Out-File`](https://learn.microsoft.com/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.utility/out-file)'s `-Encoding` parameter to control the output file's character encoding.

Comment: Awesome thanks for the help. So if I wanted to run this process for multiple computers would this be correct? Invoke-Command -ComputerName Computer 1, Computer2, Computer 3 -ScriptBlock{Get-LocalGroupMember -Name Administrators | # get all users in the groupForEach-Object Name | # extract their name Out-File NamesOfUsersInTheAdministratorsGroup.txt}